# How to make actual UWP app itself .net standard 2.0 compliant?

Tags: uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I'm seriously confused. If one wants to create a UWP application that will work correctly on any platform that implements the .Net Standard 2.0 interface, how do you insure that your application doesn't use anything outside of that interface. It seems like you cannot target .Net Standard 2.0 in the actual application, only .Net Core. All you can do is indicate you want to be able to CONSUME .Net Standard 2.0 libraries. But .Net Core is a super-set. So how will you know that your own applications aren't using APIs outside of that .Net Standard 2.0 interface?

This seems just totally bizarre to me. It's like they created a standard that no application can actually be sure it's using. It's like you'd have to put your entire application into a library essentially and have the actual application code do nothing but invoke some code in the library?

Comment: I guess I should have qualified that... the point being that, at some point once the portable stuff gets more mature, XAML standardized, etc... that it could ported over to be a portable application and be reasonably sure we've not used lots of APIs that aren't going to be available. Some sort of validation that you are sticking within the 2.0 standard seems like it would be very useful.

Comment: .netstandard applies to libraries, not final apps.  With the intention that such a library is usable in many different types of apps.  UWP dictates what the final app needs to look like, many details that are entirely non-standard.

Comment: set Min/targetBuild to at least Build 16299, here it is .net standard 2.0 compatible.